# query works in mysql but it does not work in java

Tags: java, mysql

I have a query as follow:

```
select(SELECT sum(Frequency) FROM omid.entity_epoch_data where DataitemType=0 and
EntityID in(SELECT EntityID FROM omid.entity where PartyID=2) and EpochID in(
    SELECT ID FROM omid.epoch where StartDateTime>='2013-11-01' and EndDateTime<='2013-11-30'))/
    (select count(*) from omid.entity where PartyID=2);
```

when I run it in my sql it works but when I run it in java I get some sql error.
My code is set up truly since when I replace this query with something else it works so it shows that something is wrong with the logic of using this query

Can anyone help?

Comment: It would help if you could say what error you get :)

Comment: Thanks, it says unknown error but the line that this problem happens at is : rset = stmt.executeQuery();

Comment: Could we see the actual Java code?

Comment: Showing the database schema would also help. But anyway, if you want to debug this yourself, my suggestion is that you start with a minimal query (say, the select without the and) and start adding stuff until it fails, then you know which part is making the query fail.

Comment: We need real code and a stack trace - there is nowhere near enough information here to help you find what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to find some kind of average.

But, this single select is so complicated that I am sure that neither you nor anyone that comes after you will be able to easily figure out exactly what you are trying to do.

Break it up into several smaller queries and code them separately.

Then calculate your average in Java rather then building this overly complicated query.

Or, make a stored function and call that from Java since you said that it works if you do the query from MySQL.